# Use library (Plyr) with directive and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, plyr.js

I would like to use [Plyr](https://github.com/Selz/plyr) with AngularJS, but when I install plyr with AngularJS, Plyr doesn't work

I must include :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/1.7.0/plyr.css">

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/1.7.0/plyr.js"></script>

<div id="plyr" data-type="youtube" data-video-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>

<script>
var player = plyr.setup(document.querySelector('#plyr'), {
    debug: true
});

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to create a directive :

```
(function (){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ngPlyr', []);

    angular.module('ngPlyr').directive('plyr', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div id="plyr" data-type="youtube" data-video-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>'
        };
    })

})();
```

and

```
<div plyr></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `Plyr` inside your directive in it's `link` function. Something like this should work:

```
(function (){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ngPlyr', []);

    angular.module('ngPlyr').directive('plyr', function () {
        return {
            template: '<div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="bTqVqk7FSmY"></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var player = plyr.setup(element, { debug: true });
            }
        };
    })

})();
```